# Overwriting Kohana_Core

Tags: php, kohana, overwrite

Is is possible to overwrite Kohana_Core ?

I want to add another path to widgets (they aren't the same as modules) so i have to add theme into bootstrap.php as :

```
Kohana::Widget(array());
```

I don't want to edit the class Kohana_Core (system/kohana/Core.php) but just overwrite it.

I tried to add a new file called Core.php (`Class Core extends Kohana_Core`) into my APPPATH but no way.

I use Kohana 3.3

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Get it !

Just add Kohana.php and not Core.php into APPPATH

```
Class Kohana extends Koahan_Core
{
   public static function Widget($widgets)
   {
    // Do something
   }
}
```